# Show that $61!+1$ is divisible by $71$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working on the following Wilson's theorem exercise.

> Show that $61!+1$ is divisible by $71.$

I know that expressed as a congruence it would be $61! \equiv -1 \pmod {71}$

Based on  Wilson's theorem $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$, I have

$$70! \equiv -1 \pmod {71}.$$

What I'm doing now is

$$70*69*68*...*62*61! \equiv -1 \pmod {71}.$$

But I don't know how to cancel those extra numbers I have before the 61; any hint or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you mean to type "mod 71" in your second equation.

Comment: Hint:  ${70} \equiv {-1} \pmod {71}, {69} \equiv {-2} \pmod {71}$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice:  $62*..... *70 \equiv (-9)*(-8)*.... *(-1)\equiv$

$(9*8)*(6*4*3)*(7*5*2)*(-1)^9 \equiv -(72)^2(70)\equiv -1^2*(-1) \equiv 1\pmod {71}$.

So $70! = 61!*(62*....*70) \equiv 61! \pmod {71}$.

But $71$ is prime so by Wilson's Theorem $70! \equiv - 1\pmod {71}$.

So $61! \equiv -1 \pmod{71}$ and so $71|61! + 1$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether there is some *really* clever way, but here a brute force approach is fast enough.
$$
70\cdot69\cdots62\equiv (-1)\cdot(-2)\cdots(-9)
$$
We have $$(-8)\cdot(-9)\equiv 1\\(-2)\cdot (-5)\cdot(-7)\equiv 1\\(-3)\cdot(-4)\cdot(-6)\equiv-1$$which means that $70!\equiv61!$

Answer (score 1):

$$-1 \equiv 70\times69\times68\times...\times62\times61! \equiv -1\times-2\times\cdots\times-9\times61!\equiv-9!\times61!\pmod {71}$$

Now, we need to show $-9!\equiv1\pmod{71}$, which is $362881\equiv0\pmod{71}$ which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that (the following are all $\mod 71$):
$$70 \equiv -1 $$
$$69 \equiv -2 $$
$$...$$
$$62 \equiv -9$$
$$70! \equiv (-1)(-2)...(-9)61! \equiv (-1)*61!$$